# Setting the Highchart theme

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts

I'm developing a `.NET` `mvc` based website in which I use the [Highchart library](https://www.highcharts.com/) for graphic representation. I successfully managed to build the Chart, however, the customization part takes too much space in the chart declaration + there is a lot of useless copy and paste, making my code unreadable. I have tried to move the "design" part in a separate file, I also tried to declare it only once in the file in which I'm constructing the charts, but with no success.

Is there a way, in which I can actually call the theme (defined in the Highchart/Js/Theme) folder? I tried with the `setOption` option, but failed again. (No matter what I've tried, my chart was undefined or the theme was inaccessible)

Answer (score 0):

After trying something(just thought it could work this way,I managed to solve my problem).First off all you have to declare your theme in the Folder I specified,after that all you have to do is to provide the source of the script in your _Layout file.